# About closure creation

Tags: elisp, lexical-scoping, dynamic-scoping, lexical-binding, closures

After reading this article about [readable closures](https://nullprogram.com/blog/2013/12/30/), I check that:

> Since closures are byte-code function objects, they print readably.
>   You can capture an environment in a closure, serialize it, read it
>   back in, and evaluate it. That’s pretty cool! This means closures can
>   be transmitted to other Emacs instances in a multi-processing setup
>   (i.e. Elnode, Async)

So since we can do that, we can also *write* closures?
Should this be a real possibility and will have a real use?

Writing a normal closure

```
ELISP> (setq counter (let ((x 0)) (lambda () (cl-incf x))))
(closure
 ((x . 0)
  t)
 nil
 (cl-incf x))

ELISP> (funcall counter)
1 (#o1, #x1, ?\C-a)
ELISP> counter
(closure
 ((x . 1)
  t)
 nil
 (cl-incf x))
```

Writing a literal closure:

```
ELISP> (setq even-counter '(closure ((x . 0) t) nil (cl-incf x 2)))
(closure
 ((x . 0)
  t)
 nil
 (cl-incf x 2))

ELISP> (funcall even-counter)
2 (#o2, #x2, ?\C-b)
ELISP> even-counter)
*** IELM error ***  More than one sexp in input
ELISP> even-counter
(closure
 ((x . 2)
  t)
 nil
 (cl-incf x 2))
```

So they both work, and are the same type, since they don't will have non-readable types (i.e buffer) inside they will work equally. further more they are the same type:

```
ELISP> (type-of even-counter)
cons
ELISP> (type-of counter)
cons
```

But I couldn't find any constructor for building a closure. 
So I suppose that his is one of the cases of homoiconicity of lisp.
To Sum up:

- Will be useful to write/build literal closures?
- Should it be a good practice? any example?
- Why the closure is not a real type instead of `cons`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You asked:

> - Will be useful to write/build literal closures?
> - Should it be a good practice? any example?
> - Why the closure is not a real type instead of cons?

All three questions are answered with the following quote of the [elisp manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Closures.html):

> However, the fact that the internal structure of a closure is exposed to
>   the rest of the Lisp world is considered an internal implementation
>   detail.  For this reason, we recommend against directly examining or
>   altering the structure of closure objects.

So you should **not rely on the structure** of closure objects and the answer to your first and second question is: `No´.

About your third question: `cons` is also a real type.
I think you actually ask why `(type-of counter)` does not return something closure specific but `cons`. The above quote also answers that question. Closures are currently represented by lists. Therefore `type-of` cannot differentiate between closure and a list with the symbol `closure` as first element.